# Is the term $E\left[Z^3E[Z\mid Y] \right]$ positive or negative?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $Z$ be standard normal and $Y$ some other random variable.

Is the $E\left[Z^3E[Z\mid Y] \right]$ positive or negative?
I tried a few things like using orthogonality principle
\begin{align}
E\left[Z^3E[Z\mid Y] \right]=E[E[Z^3\mid Y]E[Z\mid Y]]=E[E[Z^3\mid Y]Z]
\end{align}

but this didn't go anywhere?

This  question is related to something I asked a while ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368863/is-ez-ez2-mid-y-positive-or-negative). But now the structure of $Y$ is unspecified.

Comment: Well, if $Z$ and $Y$ are independent then it is just zero. So there's one extreme case...

Comment: Yes, good point. I should have said that $Z$ and $Y$ are correlated.

Comment: Maybe think about where $Y$ is normal, with the covariance taking on one sign or the other? My suspicion is that the sign of this expectation will be the sign of the covariance. But my suspicion might be naive.

Comment: @Boby is this really for all random variables $Y$ ?

Comment: Well. I have in mind $Y=V+Z$ where $V$ is any r.v. But  starting more genera,l I though, would be nicer.